# Prism shared region

Tags: c#, prism, region

I have a question. I created a region with view and model for a "pdf reader". Then I add this "pdf reader region" to two content controls in two usercontrols. I want to recycle this region with the view and model

The pdf reader is only a view to display a pdf file.

Bootstrapper register:

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(BaseNames.PDF_VIEW_REGION, typeof(
                    Infrastructure.Base.Views.PdfView));
```

BaseNames class

```
public static class BaseNames
{
    public const string PDF_VIEW_REGION = "PdfViewBaseRegion";
}
```

View 1

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static contract:BaseNames.PDF_VIEW_REGION }"/>
```

View 2

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static contract:BaseNames.PDF_VIEW_REGION }"/>
```

Exception:

> Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionCreationException: "An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'PdfViewBaseRegion'. The exception was: System.ArgumentException: Region with the given name is already registered: PdfViewBaseRegion
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionManager.RegionCollection.Add(IRegion region)
>      bei Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionManagerRegistrationBehavior.TryRegisterRegion()
>      bei Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionManagerRegistrationBehavior.StartMonitoringRegionManager()
>      bei Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionManagerRegistrationBehavior.OnAttach()
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionBehavior.Attach()
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionBehaviorCollection.Add(String key, IRegionBehavior regionBehavior)
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterBase`1.AttachDefaultBehaviors(IRegion region, T regionTarget)
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterBase`1.Initialize(T regionTarget, String regionName)
>      bei Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterBase`1.Prism.Regions.IRegionAdapter.Initialize(Object regionTarget, String regionName)
>      bei Prism.Regions.Behaviors.DelayedRegionCreationBehavior.CreateRegion(DependencyObject targetElement, String regionName). "

Comment: What exactly is your question? You create two regions with the same name and the exception is telling you you're not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to View that uses RegionManager, you should remove your Region from RegionCollection in RegionManager.

```
    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.RegionManager.Regions.Remove(BaseNames.PDF_VIEW_REGION);
    }
```